# Infinite Loop when setting requireADLogin: true, on $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following piece of code, what I want is instead of use the route provider, use the state provider.

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,
    $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, $httpProvider) {

    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
       {
           instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
           tenant: 'mysaasapp.onmicrosoft.com',
           clientId: '33e037a7-b1aa-42ab-9693-6c22d01ca338',
           extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
           //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
       },
       $httpProvider
       );

    // Configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
    IdleProvider.timeout(120); // in seconds

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard_1");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
        debug: false
    });

    $stateProvider

        .state('dashboards', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboards",
            templateUrl: "views/common/content.html",
        })
        .state('dashboards.dashboard_1', {
            url: "/dashboard_1",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard_1.html",
            //requireADLogin: true,
```

If I uncomment the requireADLogin, then I have an infinite loop. If comment then it works again but without the authentication I need.

So maybe the state provider doesnt support it and I am forced to use route provider?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ui-Router 404 when redirecting with ADAL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428427/ui-router-404-when-redirecting-with-adal)